# Pure CSS3 animations and rotations in Chrome not returning correctly to appropriate state

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to manage a series of rotations, shrink effects, and highlighting effects purely using CSS3 class changes in order to restrict the JS usage to applying class changes only. I'm also restricted to using Chrome.

I'm running into an issue where the browser does not seem to be respecting the transformation specified by the class.

My goal here is to move through the steps:

1. full animation
2. paused and shrunk animation
3. highlight two images by pulling them out and rotating them into correct viewing angle
4. restore the images into the paused stack at the correct rotation of their peers
5. restore full animation

To do this, I am defining the default state for my images (which in this circumstance are all cats) as rotations in paused animation:

```
/* Define the default bevaviour as a paused rotation */
 .cat {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-60px) translateY(100px) translateZ(0px) rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(30deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 50%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    -webkit-animation: all 10s linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    width: 500px;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-transition: all;
    transition: all 4s ease;
}
```

The parent div has classes applied to it in order to control the animation behaviour, followed by additional classes to control highlight behaviour - this is detailed at:

http://jsfiddle.net/kaiesh/m3str/5/

however this results in the highlight working improperly, the highlighted images **do not rotate into the correct orientation**.

I tried to resolve this by applying an animation class to the image that is in running state (I've done this one of the cat images in the example) - you can see that here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kaiesh/m3str/6/

However in this second example the rotation jumps around, and then after that, when restored to the shrunk version with its peers **does not stop rotating, even though the animation play state is marked as paused**.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: You could start by prefixing your code with an online prefixer, to see if in another, non webkit browser it works as intended, or if the error is in the code / math...

Comment: I'm restricted to using Chrome, so any solution I can deploy needs to be targeted for that browser. I'll prepare a fiddle that can be used to preview in other browsers for reference and update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stop and replay an animation on transforms, you can not change the transform of the element. Or, may be better, it's too tricky to go this way.

Much better if you handle this in another element; in this case the images itselves.

First of all, let's add an easy to retrieve property to the animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes allcats {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        z-index: 0;}
  100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(360deg) rotateY(0deg);
        z-index: 360;}
}
```

That is because transforms are retrieved as a matrix, and the it's quiet complicated to get the angle. This way, retrieving the z-index you know directly what the rotation is.

Now set the opposite rotation on the images, to get them straight

```
$('#stage-2').click(function (e) {
    var step = $("#image2").css("z-index");
    $("#image2").addClass("upper");
    $("#image3").addClass("lower");
    $("#image2 img").css("webkitTransform", "rotate(-"+step+"deg)");
    $("#image3 img").css("webkitTransform", "rotate(-"+step+"deg)");
});
```

Reset the rotation to none:

```
$('#stage-3').click(function (e) {
    //$("#left1 .cat").addClass("cat-stopped").removeClass("cat-rotate");
    $("#image2").removeClass("upper");
    $("#image3").removeClass("lower");
    $("#image2 img").css("webkitTransform", "");
    $("#image3 img").css("webkitTransform", "");
});
```

and do it smoothly

```
.cat img {
    transition: all 4s ease;
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3str/8/)